# error in calling event(new Registered($user)); method in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, email, verification

I'm working on a Laravel project with a React front-end. After submitting a new user, I am trying to send a verification email to the user, but I keep getting the following error:

Error: Typed property DOMDocument::$documentElement must not be accessed before initialization in file /home/hitmug/public_html/api.hitmug.ir/vendor/tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles/src/CssToInlineStyles.php on line 132
I have implemented MustVerifyEmail in my user model. Here is the code that gave me the error:

```
public function mail_verification()
{
   $user = \auth()->user();
   event(new Registered($user));
   return Response()->json('ok');
}
```

I tried using event(new Registered($user));. What could be causing this error and how can I fix it?